# apt-get upgrade to a certain state

Tags: apt

Let's say I have two servers, a test server and a production server. First I do `apt-get upgrade` on the test server. Then after extensive testing two weeks later I want the production server to be at the exact same state packagewise. Is it possible to somehow `apt-get upgrade` to a certain state instead of always latest?

Comment: Are your servers using Debian or Ubuntu? It does matter here. I have an answer for Debian. The difference boils down to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/499871/is-there-ubuntus-analogue-of-snapshot-debian-org

Answer (score 6):

OP didn't tell what distribution on the server is in use. So by default I'll consider it's Debian since `apt` was "invented" by Debian, and the needed service is only available for Debian.

While for a single package forcing the version with `=` is fine and handy especially to revert it (if still available), for a collection of packages it can quickly become a nightmare because of unmet dependencies.

What can be done is to use a repository URL built from https://snapshot.debian.org/. This service holds a copy of all package versions made since 2009 and is [officially available since 2010](https://www.debian.org/News/2010/20100412):

> The snapshot service also enables administrators to install a
>   predictable, tested set of packages by using a view of the archive on
>   a given date. This feature allows administrators to test an upgrade
>   path in a staging environment and then repeat the procedure in their
>   production environment with assurance that they are performing exactly
>   the tested upgrade. As the snapshot covers the entire archive and all
>   suites this can be applied to environments that wish to track testing
>   in a controlled manner as well as those with more stringent change
>   control who wish to fully audit all stable updates before rolling them
>   out.

A first requirement is to have https transport available: `apt-get install apt-transport-https` (sorry it might pull a few dependencies which might have been upgraded meanwhile).

Let's suppose you want the packages from two weeks ago, ie 2018-12-07. Following the instructions on the site, you can browse:

```
https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181207/
```

Which will point to a [more fine-tuned URL](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181206T232234Z/), probably in UTC time. You can then navigate there "through time" to suit your needs, probably with a few "[next change](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181207T090635Z/)".

Once the time is fine, just use this as a base deb URL., in a sources.list file:

eg `/etc/apt/sources.d/snapshot-20181207.list` with for example content:

```
deb https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181207T090635Z/ stretch main
```

Since the snapshots are in the past, with older package versions, if the default choice is left to apt, it will use newer versions anyway instead and always ignore those available there. the `-t` flag of apt is of no use for this, because it's still the same release. So [apt's preferences](https://manpages.debian.org/apt_preferences.5.en.html) have to be tweaked. Have an entry in a file ending in `.pref` in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`, eg `/etc/apt/preferences.d/00-snapshot-20181207.list` (order of preferences can matter here):

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "snapshot.debian.org"
Pin-Priority: 900
```

This will put all packages from snapshot.debian.org at priority 900 which is higher than 500 for default (and newer) packages, giving it priority over other repositories, including security which is the main source of updates in a short time lapse. Since it's still lower priority than when adding `-t stable`, one can compare the difference between the upgrade to the state at 2018-12-07 or to today.

Using 1001 would even allow (and force) to downgrade packages, which can be dangerous (eg, but not limited to: when a file was moved from a package to an other due to packaging changes, this file can be lost when downgrading) but can still be useful.

If `apt-get update` complains about an expired Release file, which it will after 12 days, as explained on the site, you'll have to either use `apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update` or (since Debian 9) add a `[check-valid-until=no]` in the source entry, to disable the check. That's why https transport is used: to have an other security layer anyway. So replace contents of `snapshot-20181207.list` with:

```
deb [check-valid-until=no] https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181207T090635Z/ stretch main
```

UPDATE: security is in a separate snapshot archive: [debian-security](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/?year=2018&month=12). So this entry (or one to an other date) should also be added:

```
deb [check-valid-until=no] https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20181206T212649Z/ stretch/updates main
```

Now, doing the usual `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` should upgrade all packages to the 2018-12-07 versions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

In short, if you want to upgrade `foo` to version 2.5, instead of running `apt upgrade foo`, you would run `apt upgrade foo=2.5`

This means you will want to get a dump of the installed versions on your test server, then use that information to get the production server to the same state.

Comment: You also need a repository which still has all the versions you need.

Comment: @StephenKitt true but running your own mirror is trivial if needed. Or simply copy the `/var/cache/apt/archives/*deb` from the dev machine (assuming you didn't `apt-get clean`)

Comment: @ivanivan agreed, but it still should be addressed in the answer. I’m not saying the answer’s wrong, only incomplete.