# Debian mdadm: No devices listed in conf file were found

Tags: debian, boot, raid, mdadm

My Debian sid machine had been booting kernel 4.13 from a raid array for several months without issue. 2 days ago I upgraded the platform and now booting fails like this:
[image]

Additionally, the initramfs prompt does not accept any input, so I cannot investigate from there.

I have an older kernel (4.9*)) which still boots fine.

These things I tried so far:

- Used kernel param "rootdelay=10"
- Installed a newer kernel (4.19): fails the same way
- Compared the initrams of 4.13 and 4.9: the init script had some changes. Downgraded initramfs-tools from 132 to 130, now the initrams are same (according to diff on extracted files), but 4.13 still has that issue.
- The mentioned UUID c28..e99 is correct

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

*) Which I cannot use because compiling the NVIDIA module fails [because of unknown rela relocation](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/903xwq/unable_to_compile_working_kernel_modules_anymore/) and I don't want to downgrade binutils (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new bug affecting at least Debian sid, testing (so near to a freeze...) (and also [Archlinux](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61328)) related to systemd 240, more specifically to its udev component, possibly `udevadm`: [udev 240 Makes System Unbootable; rootfs Not Found](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917607)

This bug leads to no devices being enumerated in `/dev` by udev: no disk (perhaps only no `/dev/disk/`, so no UUID rather than no `/dev/sda`?). Probably same with no USB enumeration so no keyboard unless it's a PS/2 port, etc. can't really tell.

It's not related to the kernel, but upgrading kernel as well as boot components triggers the rebuild of the initramfs boot part: make a backup of the still working 4.9 kernel's initramfs file, it can still be lost later.

Reverting to [udev (and libudev1) 239-15](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181231T220010Z/pool/main/s/systemd/) is said to fix the issue for now. Be sure initramfs is rebuilt for all kernels not just the current one.

UPDATE: `udev` 240-4 in sid [includes](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/commit/647f8894a374e5994eb8bab93d981e4c44bd7857) the [upstream fix](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/ee0b9e721a368742ac6fa9c3d9a33e45dc3203a2) for this issue:

> ```
>   * sd-device-monitor: Fix ordering of setting buffer size.
>     Fixes an issue with uevents not being processed properly during coldplug
>     stage and some kernel modules not being loaded via "udevadm trigger".
>     (Closes: #917607)
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, downgrading udev and libudev1 from 240-3 to 232-25+deb9u6 (no other available in the repo) did the trick. Ah, yes, and "scrounging up a ps/2 keyboard" as OP of [#917607](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917607) did, let me work from the initramfs prompt.

Comment: Additional question for my understanding: is udev installed inside the initram? If so, my diff should have spotted a difference to the 4.9 one. If not, meaning the same udev is called regardless which kernel (and initram) I boot, should not 4.9 be also affected by udev 240's issue?

Comment: udev is inside the initramfs. upgrading udev triggers rebuild of current kernel's initramfs, older is left untouched.

Comment: also follow the link at the end of my answer: https://snapshot.debian.org/ does have the packages [there](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20181231T220010Z/pool/main/s/systemd/). see my answer there if you really need it in a repo: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490356/251756 (including the comment on number 1001) but you can rely on https and download it directly too

Comment: and last comment: diff is not meant to compare binary files. udevadm is a binary executable, diff would only display binary files differ

Comment: @holunda fix in sid now