# Arch: root partition not found at boot

Tags: boot, partition

For an unknown reason, my system stopped booting.
Now, it fails to find my root partition after 10 sec and drops me in an emergency shell where my keyboard is not detected

[image: syscrash]

What I did so far was to boot from a live CD and ran the following commands.

With sdc7 my root partition
`sudo su
mkdir /mnt
mount /dev/sdc7 /mnt`

With sdc2 my EFI partition
`mkdir /mnt/boot
mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/boot`

`modprobe efivars
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -t devpts pts /mnt/dev/pts/
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
chroot /mnt`

`pacman -Syu
mkinitcpio -P
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"`

No success

NB:  I think the acpi errors on the photo are not new

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked /etc/fstab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in systemd's udev (more precisely communication between `udevadm` and `udevd`) affecting distributions shipping udev 240 but not systemd 240 in initramfs.

For Archlinux:  [FS#61328 - udev 240 not recognising keyboard](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61328)

My answer for Debian [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494087/251756).

The effect is that enumeration in `/dev` is missing or incomplete. This prevent the `/dev/disk/` tree to be filled, including UUID symlinks. It will also prevent keyboard detection etc.

The usual fix is to revert to udev 239 (so after your `chroot`) and rebuild the initramfs. It's possible that having systemd (not busybox) handling boot during initramfs can fix this problem too (because some settings get a bigger buffer used for communication between `udevadm` and `udevd` then), if that's possible on Archlinux.

Upstream bug report, fix proposition and fix commit there. It boils down to allow a bigger buffer for communication (and is probably not the best fix):

[udev fails to trigger loading of modules #11314](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11314)
[Set systemd-udevd monitor buffer size to 128MB #11389](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/11389)
[sd-device-monitor: fix ordering of setting buffer size](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/ee0b9e721a368742ac6fa9c3d9a33e45dc3203a2)

Comment: Last update of systemd (240.34-2) fixed it