# After updating to nvidia 390.87 black screen on login

Tags: debian, nvidia

I'm running debian

```
las@thinkpad:~$ uname -a
Linux thinkpad-nc 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and just updated to the kernel above. I've also updated the nvidia drivers to `390.87`. I have a GTX 1050. After the upgrade the login screen is simply black. I've tried to run a `nvidia-xconfig` however it didn't resolve my issue. Below is the output of the `Xorg.log` as well as my new Xorg.conf generated via `nvidia-xconfig`.

`Xorg.0.log`

```
las@thinkpad:~$ cat /media/nicolas/86403a2e-46c5-4188-bede-d55bed56809d/Xorg.0.log 
[    21.493] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[    21.493] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    21.493] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    21.493] Current Operating System: Linux thinkstation 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64
[    21.493] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=UUID=af9e3ec9-ee68-4bee-a647-a28c64c7802f ro quiet
[    21.493] Build Date: 03 November 2018  03:09:11AM
[    21.493] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[    21.493] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    21.493]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    21.493] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    21.493] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Feb 27 09:30:19 2019
[    21.508] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    21.508] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    21.874] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    21.874] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    21.874] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    21.887] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    21.887] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    21.887] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    21.887] (**) Option "Xinerama" "0"
[    21.887] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    21.887] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    21.887] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    21.887] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    22.050] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    22.155]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    22.293] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    22.293] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    22.293] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    22.293] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    22.293] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    22.293] (II) Loader magic: 0x55ac65c0ee00
[    22.293] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    22.293]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    22.293]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    22.293]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    22.293]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    22.294] (++) using VT number 7

[    22.295] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    22.295] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    22.297] (--) PCI:*(0:3:0:0) 10de:1c81:1458:372b rev 161, Mem @ 0xca000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xce000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00002000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    22.297] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    22.607] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[    24.883] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    24.883]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    24.883]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    24.890] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.87  Tue Aug 21 16:10:56 PDT 2018
[    24.900] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    24.973] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[    25.123] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    25.123]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    25.123]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    25.134] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.87  Tue Aug 21 15:44:49 PDT 2018
[    25.134] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    25.141] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    25.141] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    25.141] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    25.250] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.250]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    25.250]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    25.250] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    25.250] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    25.250] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    25.256] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.256]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    25.256]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    25.256] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    25.256] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    25.256] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    25.259] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    25.259] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    25.259] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "Off"
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[    25.259] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[    25.260] (**) NVIDIA(0): Stereo disabled by request
[    25.260] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA SLI disabled.
[    25.260] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[    25.260] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +3000+420, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +4920+420, HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right}, HDMI-2: nvidia-auto-select +1080+420; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60_0 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_50 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1600x900 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1440x900 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x800 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_60_0 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_50 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1152x864 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x576 +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x480 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1366x768, viewportout=1920x1079+0+0}"
[    25.260] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:3:0:0
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[    26.295] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[    26.296] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1050 (GP107-A) at PCI:3:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.07.31.00.4b
[    26.296] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.296] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-1): connected
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): connected
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[    26.327] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.328] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.329] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    26.329] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    26.329] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.329] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.359] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-4): connected
[    26.359] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-4): Internal TMDS
[    26.359] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-4): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.359] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.389] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-5): connected
[    26.389] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-5): Internal TMDS
[    26.389] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-5): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    26.389] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):    
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DP-0:nvidia-auto-select+3000+420,HDMI-0:nvidia-auto-select+4920+420,HDMI-1:nvidia-auto-select+0+0{rotation=right},HDMI-2:nvidia-auto-select+1080+420"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:nvidia-auto-select+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1920x1080_60_0+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1920x1080_50+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1680x1050+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1600x900+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1440x900+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x1024+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x1024_60+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x800+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x720+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x720_60_0+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1280x720_50+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1152x864+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1024x768+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1024x768_70+0+0"
[    26.413] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:1024x768_60+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:800x600+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:800x600_72+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:800x600_60+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:800x600_56+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:720x576+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:720x480+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:640x480+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:640x480_72+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:640x480_60+0+0"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):    
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "HDMI-0:nvidia-auto-select+0+0{viewportin=1366x768,viewportout=1920x1079+0+0}"
[    26.414] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 6840 x 1920
[    26.419] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (93, 94); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    26.419] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    26.419] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    26.421] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    26.421] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[    26.424] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[    26.484] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-0:nvidia-auto-select+3000+420,HDMI-0:nvidia-auto-select+4920+420,HDMI-1:nvidia-auto-select+0+0{rotation=right},HDMI-2:nvidia-auto-select+1080+420"
[    35.560] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    35.560] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    35.560] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    35.562] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    35.563] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    35.563] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    35.563] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    35.563] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    35.563] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    35.563] (--) RandR disabled
[    35.566] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    35.567] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    35.567] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[    36.017] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    36.017] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    36.017] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    36.029] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    36.065] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    36.065]    compiled for 1.19.0, module version = 0.23.0
[    36.065]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    36.065]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    36.065] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    36.065] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    36.065] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    36.065] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    36.065] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.065] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    36.092] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input6/event3"
[    36.092] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    36.092] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    36.092] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    36.092] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[    36.120] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.120] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    36.121] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    36.121] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    36.121] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    36.121] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    36.121] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    36.121] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    36.121] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.121] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    36.156] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input5/event2"
[    36.156] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    36.156] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    36.156] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    36.156] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[    36.157] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.157] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[    36.157] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event14)
[    36.157] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.158] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.158] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event15)
[    36.158] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.158] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.159] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event16)
[    36.159] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.159] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.159] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    36.159] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.159] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.160] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event8)
[    36.160] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.160] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.160] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out Front (/dev/input/event9)
[    36.160] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.160] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.161] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event10)
[    36.161] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.161] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.161] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event11)
[    36.161] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.161] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.162] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line Out Side (/dev/input/event12)
[    36.162] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.162] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.162] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event13)
[    36.162] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.162] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.163] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event5)
[    36.163] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.163] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.163] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    36.163] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.163] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.164] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB RECEIVER (/dev/input/event0)
[    36.164] (**) Logitech USB RECEIVER: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    36.164] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB RECEIVER'
[    36.164] (**) Logitech USB RECEIVER: always reports core events
[    36.164] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    36.164] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    36.165] (II) input device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    36.165] (II) Device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER' set to 800 DPI
[    36.165] (II) input device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER', /dev/input/event0 is a pointer caps
[    36.232] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:046D:C50E.0001/input/input3/event0"
[    36.232] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB RECEIVER" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    36.232] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    36.232] (**) Logitech USB RECEIVER: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    36.232] (**) Logitech USB RECEIVER: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    36.232] (**) Logitech USB RECEIVER: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    36.233] (II) input device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    36.233] (II) Device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER' set to 800 DPI
[    36.233] (II) input device 'Logitech USB RECEIVER', /dev/input/event0 is a pointer caps
[    36.234] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB RECEIVER (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    36.234] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.234] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.235] (II) config/udev: Adding input device CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[    36.235] (**) CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    36.235] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard'
[    36.235] (**) CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard: always reports core events
[    36.235] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    36.235] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    36.235] (II) input device 'CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.235] (II) input device 'CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    36.272] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:04B3:3025.0002/input/input4/event1"
[    36.272] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    36.272] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    36.272] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    36.272] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[    36.273] (II) input device 'CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.273] (II) input device 'CHICONY USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    36.273] (II) config/udev: Adding input device UVC Camera (046d:0825) (/dev/input/event17)
[    36.274] (**) UVC Camera (046d:0825): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    36.274] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)'
[    36.274] (**) UVC Camera (046d:0825): always reports core events
[    36.274] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event17"
[    36.274] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    36.274] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)', /dev/input/event17 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.274] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)', /dev/input/event17 is a keyboard
[    36.304] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input20/event17"
[    36.304] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "UVC Camera (046d:0825)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    36.304] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    36.304] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "ch"
[    36.304] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[    36.305] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)', /dev/input/event17 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    36.305] (II) input device 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)', /dev/input/event17 is a keyboard
[    36.305] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event4)
[    36.305] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    36.305] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    36.321] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): connected
[    36.321] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): Internal DisplayPort
[    36.321] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S24E650 (DFP-2): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    36.321] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    75.776] (II) SYN_DROPPED event from "Logitech USB RECEIVER" - some input events have been lost.
[    89.776] (II) SYN_DROPPED event from "Logitech USB RECEIVER" - some input events have been lost.
```

and here is my `xorg.conf`

```
las@thinkpad:~$ cat /media/nicolas/86403a2e-46c5-4188-bede-d55bed56809d/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.87  (buildd@debian)  Tue Feb  5 22:28:34 UTC 2019

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 375.66  (buildd@debian)  Tue May 30 08:42:42 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung S24E650"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +3000+420, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +4920+420, HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right}, HDMI-2: nvidia-auto-select +1080+420; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60_0 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1920x1080_50 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1600x900 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1440x900 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x800 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_60_0 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1280x720_50 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1152x864 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; HDMI-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x576 +0+0; HDMI-0: 720x480 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; HDMI-0: 640x480_60 +0+0; HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1366x768, viewportout=1920x1079+0+0}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: A bug report to Debian would probably be useful. Meanwhile you can dowgrade one or both by using snapshot.debian.org (eg my answer there https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490340/apt-get-upgrade-to-a-certain-state/490356#490356 , take notice of the value "1001" in the explanations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Lenovo laptop with switchable (Intel) graphics (hostname thinkpad)?
If so, it might help if you post your model and bios version.

[Chapter 17. Using the NVIDIA Driver with Optimus Laptops](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.87/README/optimus.html)

> The driver may be installed normally on Optimus systems, but the NVIDIA X driver and the NVIDIA OpenGL driver may not be able to display to the laptop's internal display panel unless a means to connect the panel to the NVIDIA GPU (for example, a hardware multiplexer, or "mux", often controllable by a BIOS setting) is available. On systems without a mux, the NVIDIA GPU can still be useful for offscreen rendering, running CUDA applications, and other uses that don't require driving a display.

Do you have 4 monitors connected (DFP-1, DFP-2, DFP-4, DFP-5, listed in your `Xorg.0.log`)? How many displays do you have and how should they be configured?

[Chapter 12. Configuring Multiple Display Devices on One X Screen](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.87/README/configtwinview.html)

> If multiple X screens are configured on the GPU, the NVIDIA X driver will attempt to reserve display devices and GPU resources for those other X screens (honoring the "UseDisplayDevice" and "MetaModes" X configuration options of each X screen) and then allocate all remaining resources to the first X screen configured on the GPU.

If you intend to use multiple devices on one X screen (Xinerama is disabled with `Option "Xinerama" "0"` and `MetaModes` are defined), have you tried `Option "UseDisplayDevice" "string"` in your `xorg.conf`? With this option you can specify the device(s) to use for X.

Example:

```
Option "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-2, DFP-3"
```

Also, check if your `MetaModes` are correct (or remove them). Shouldn't this be DFP-1, DFP-2, DFP-4, DFP-5 instead of DP-0, HDMI-0, HDMI-1, HDMI-2?
I'm not sure if this can be and where these settings come from. Maybe they are totally fine, but in the link above they also describe settings like `"DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select {...}`".

```
    Option metamodes DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +3000+420, 
    HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +4920+420, 
    HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right}, 
    HDMI-2: nvidia-auto-select +1080+420;
    ...
    ...
```

In your logfile should be a line like "`(II) NVIDIA(0): Display device(s) assigned to X screen 0:`", but is missing (while "`Valid display device(s)`" is present). See [Appendix C. Display Device Names](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.87/README/displaydevicenames.html).

If you have multiple monitors, try to get one monitor running first.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've managed to get one step further. No it's not a thinkpad. It's a thinkstation. I'm using a Nvidie GTX 1050 graphic cards. I have 4 monitors attached, three via HDMI one via DisplayPort. I had to disconnect all the screens except one. Then I got a proper login screen. I then attached the other screens. What is weird is: Three seem to work while the forth is not recognized. I'm not at the workstation right now but will add my updated xorg.conf.